# Why i get KeyError: 'TIME' running this code. This error i got when tried fasten graph with slider

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

i just don't undestand why this code dont working
Something wrong in def update_figure(selected, year_value)
The dataset have year which named 'TIME'

```
app.layout = html.Div([
                                 dcc.Graph(id="my-graph"),

                                 ], className="container"),
                       html.Div(dcc.Slider(
                           df['TIME'].min(),
                           df['TIME'].max(),
                           step=None,
                           id='crossfilter-year--slider',
                           value=(df['TIME'].max() - 1),
                           marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['TIME'].unique()}
                       ), style={'width': '100%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 0px'})
                       ])


@app.callback(
    Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('value-selected', 'value'),
    Input('crossfilter-year--slider', 'value')

)

def update_figure(selected, year_value):
    df = fd
    dff = df.loc[df['TIME'] == year_value]
    dff['hover_text'] = dff["LOCATION"] + ": " + dff[selected].apply(str)
    trace = go.Choropleth(locations=dff['LOCATION'], z=np.log(dff[selected]['TIME']),
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error, a sample of the data you're using, and where you define `df` and `fd` so we can help figure out what's wrong.